# javascript : How to create new instance from class without using new keyword

Tags: class, ecmascript-6

I want to create simple plugin with ES6 using classes . but without using new keyword . it possible to return new instance from class automatically .

example :

```
class Rectangle{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x,
        this.y = y
    }

    eq(){
        console.log('Result ' + this.x * this.y )
    }

}

const myRect = new Rectangle(10, 10);
myRect.eq();
```

I want to use like this

```
Rectangle.eq(10, 10);
```

Comment: Why use classes if you don't seem to need them? Classes are probably not the right solution to your problem. You could add a static method like `static eq(x, y) { return new this(x, y).eq(); }` to achieve what you want, but unless there is more to it than you are showing, a class is unnecessary.

Comment: I think the question is... is there a way to turn "eq()" into a class method instead of an instance method but that doesn't make any sense with "this" in the definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use module design pattern.

```
var Rectangle = (function() {
  return {
    eq: function(x, y) {
      console.log(x * y);
    }
  };
})();

Rectangle.eq(2,5);
```

Check here for reference : https://scotch.io/bar-talk/4-javascript-design-patterns-you-should-know

Comment: In this case, even if you remove construct it will still work : https://jsfiddle.net/dhgp1jwp/1/

Answer (score 1):

Define `eq()` as a [static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Static_methods). Then you don't have to instantiate your class, but can use it directly.

Comment: it working but Should not be used 'this' keyword inside a function

Comment: Yes, because `this` refers to the instance of the class. When you're using a static method, you don't have an instance.

Comment: Thank you . but i have problem with call function inside another function 
https://jsfiddle.net/ceuyxqbg/ 
Uncaught TypeError: this.msg is not a function

Comment: @ИскренХаджинедев: That's not completely correct. What `this` refers to depends on how a function is called. If a static method is called as `Foo.bar()`, then `this` inside `bar` will refer to `Foo`, i.e. the class/constructor function itself.

Comment: @FelixKling Can you send me basic template for create javascript plugin with option

Comment: @FelixKling "What this refers to depends on how a function is called. If a static method is called as Foo.bar(), then this inside bar will refer to Foo"
How to bind this to refers my class like react foo.bind(this) with pure javascript

Answer (score 0):

Reflect.construct does the same thing:

```js
class Rectangle{
    constructor(x, y){
        this.x = x,
        this.y = y
    }

    eq(){
        console.log('Result ' + this.x * this.y )
    }

}

Reflect.construct(Rectangle, [10, 10]).eq();
```